# Neo4j 3.x - LogVersion exception at graph shutdown

Tags: java, exception, neo4j

My project is using Neo4j in embedded mode, I'm trying to populate an empty db with the batch inserter standard java API. I however get a weird exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entry type 104 for version 0. At position LogPosition{logVersion=23, byteOffset=16} and entry version V2_0
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.LogEntryVersion.entryParser(LogEntryVersion.java:141)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.entry.VersionAwareLogEntryReader.readLogEntry(VersionAwareLogEntryReader.java:84)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource$2.getTimestampForVersion(NeoStoreDataSource.java:616)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.PhysicalLogFileInformation.getFirstStartRecordTimestamp(PhysicalLogFileInformation.java:97)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.pruning.EntryTimespanThreshold.reached(EntryTimespanThreshold.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.pruning.ThresholdBasedPruneStrategy.prune(ThresholdBasedPruneStrategy.java:68)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.pruning.LogPruningImpl.pruneLogs(LogPruningImpl.java:54)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.doCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:224)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.log.checkpoint.CheckPointerImpl.forceCheckPoint(CheckPointerImpl.java:114)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.NeoStoreDataSource.stop(NeoStoreDataSource.java:887)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.stop(LifeSupport.java:457)
        ... 19 more
```

Checking the source code of Neo4j, this should happen when conflicting versions of LogEntry are provided. I never set that LogEntry version, and I cannot trace from where it is coming from.

I was wondering if someone had a similar issue? I've been having this error and tried versions 3.0.0 to 3.1.0-M4.

More info on this ticket https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/7204